# How do I print the current working directory of another user in linux?

Tags: linux, unix, command, pwd

Is there a command line I can issue to see what directory another user is currently working in? This would be like using *>pwd* but for the other user.

Comment: Maybe some information here may help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-report-current-working-directory-of-process.html

Comment: no one cmdline, only ways

Comment: "Users" don't have cwds... Processes do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `cwd` symlink in every process' `/proc` folder, but as a commoner you wouldn't have any rights to read any other's proc folder - only your own:

```
[marc@panic home]$ ls -l /proc/$$/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 marc marc 0 May  5 12:06 /proc/16257/cwd -> /home
                                                          ^^^^^---cwd
[marc@panic home]$
            ^^^^---cwd
```

Comment: What if I have sudo as root. Can I run cwd for another user?

Comment: Sure you can do the above, but you need the process id to query by. Note that "the current working directory" does not make sense in relation to a user account, but only of a process. Different processes of a user can and will have different working directories. A user account does not have a working directory.

Comment: Assuming I had the following:
>who
jsmith  console  Apr 30 10:03
adam  ttys000  Apr 30 10:04
bob  ttys001  Apr 30 10:04
What command could I issue with this technique to see the 'cwd' of bob?

Comment: that doesn't tell you anything. you've got a username. but that shell can have MANY background tasks, and each task can have a different working directory.if you want to know what a user's terminal shell is sitting at for a directory, then you'd have to figure out what process is their shell (e.g. bash, sh, csh, etc..) and get that process' cwd.